# Is it possible to provide translations for CollaborationGroup object?

Tags: force.com, administration, configuration, translation, translation-workbench

I have created a few groups in my dev org, I am checking to see if there is an option to provide translations for the group names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly did chrome inspect on the API names of the Setup component supported by translation workbench.

```
QuickActionDefinition
AddressCountry
AddressState
CustomShareRowCause
TabSet
WebLink
ChatterExtension
CustomFieldDefinition
CustomReportType
DataCategory
DataCategoryGroup
FeedFilterDefinition
FieldSet
FlowDefinition
SharedPicklistDefinition
LayoutSection
NamedFilter
Topic
ModerationRule
NavigationMenuItem
PathAssistantStepInfo
PicklistMaster
RecordType
ReputationLevel"
Scontrol
CategoryNode
Stamp
FieldAttributes
UserCustomBadge
ValidationFormula
CustomTabDefinition
ActionTask
```

As we could not see **CollaborationGroup**  I belive its not supported.